# WinRar zip multiple folders via cli

Tags: zip, command-line-interface, rar, winrar

I have a working code :`rar.lnk a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m0 -r -y "Q:\zaloha\zaloha_.rar" "D:\"`

This should "backup" my whole D drive, and save it into Q/Zaloha folder .... But i want to add more "saved" folder into rar file not just "D:\", but  "C:\Omega" and "C:\Hare" too

Is this even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
rar.lnk a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m0 -r -y "Q:\zaloha\zaloha_.rar" "D:\"  "C:\Omega" "C:\Hare"
```